# Why can't I define a readonly variable named path in zsh?

Tags: shell, zsh, variable

In zsh, `path` is a special array variable, the contents of which is linked to the well-known `PATH` variable.

So special, in fact, that defining and calling the function

```
f() { local -r path=42 }
```

causes the error `f: read-only variable: path`. If the local variable is declared as mutable (i.e. without `-r`), everything works as expected. I haven't been able to reproduce this error with other variable names.

Why does this error occur and is it intentional? Do similar rules exist for other names?

I'm using zsh 5.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin16.0) on macOS 10.12.6.

Comment: forwarded to the zsh developer mailing list: https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2017/msg01715.html

Comment: add an `-h` to the command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR don't reuse "special builtin parameter" such as `path` because uh they're special. Or according to [The Mailing List](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2017/msg01716.html) one can use the `-h` flag:

```
% () { local -hr path=42; echo $path }
42
%
```

(However changing `path` to an integer might mess up subsequent code that forgets this override and assumes `path` is instead `path`...)

Longer digging around follows (but I totally missed the `-h` hide thing...)

```
% print ${(t)path}
array-special
```

This is a property (feature? bug?) of special variables, but not similar variables linked by the user:

```
% () { typeset -r PATH=/blah; echo $PATH }
(anon): read-only variable: PATH
% typeset -Tar FOO=bar foo
% print $foo
bar
% print ${(t)foo}
array-readonly-tag_local
% () { local -r foo=blah; echo $foo }
blah
```

There are various other parameters that exhibit this behavior:

```
% for p in $parameters[(I)*]; do print $p $parameters[$p]; done | grep array-
cdpath array-special
...
% () { local -r cdpath=42 }
(anon): read-only variable: cdpath
```

So some variables are like in *Animal Farm* more special than others. This error message comes from various places in `Src/params.c` which if that is modified to print which message is the specific message we on compiling that `zsh` find:

```
% () { local -r path }
% () { local -r path=foo }
(anon): read-only variable (setarrvalue): path
```

Is the rather generic code

```
/**/
mod_export void
setarrvalue(Value v, char **val)
{
    if (unset(EXECOPT))
        return;
    if (v->pm->node.flags & PM_READONLY) {
        zerr("read-only variable (setarrvalue): %s", v->pm->node.nam);
        freearray(val);
        return;
    }
```

This shows that the problem happens elsewhere; non-special variables doubtless do not have `PM_READONLY` set while the special variables that fail do. The next obvious place to look is the code for `local` which goes by a variety of names (`typeset` `export` ...). These are all builtins so can be found lurking in the depths of `Src/builtin.c`

```
% grep BUILTIN Src/builtin.c | grep local
    BUILTIN("local", BINF_PLUSOPTS | BINF_MAGICEQUALS | BINF_PSPECIAL | BINF_ASSIGN, (HandlerFunc)bin_typeset, 0, -1, 0, "AE:%F:%HL:%R:%TUZ:%ahi:%lp:%rtux", NULL),
```

These all call `bin_typeset` with various flags set so let's study the source for that function...swearing in the comments, check. Notes that things are complicated, check. Nothing really jumps out, though the rabbit hole (for when the "treat arguments as patterns" `-m` option is *not* set, which is the case here) appears to lead to the `typeset_single` function...

There is some code for `POSIXBUILTINS` related to `readonly`, but that's turned off in my test shells

```
% print $options[POSIXBUILTINS]
off
```

so I'm going to ignore that code (I hope. Could this be a shoggoth lair and no mere rabbit hole?). Meanwhile! Some debugging points to the `PM_READONLY` flag being toggled on for `path` by the following line

```
    /*
     * The remaining on/off flags should be harmless to use,
     * because we've checked for unpleasant surprises above.
     */
    pm->node.flags = (PM_TYPE(pm->node.flags) | on | PM_SPECIAL) & ~off;
```

Which in turn comes from the `on` variable which in turn is already on when the `typeset_single` function is entered, sigh, so back to `bin_typeset` we go... okay, basically there's a `TYPESET_OPTSTR` that somehow via some macros enables `PM_READONLY` by default; when instead a user-supplied variable runs through this code path the `PM_READONLY` gets turned off and all is well.

Whether this can be changed so that special variables such as `path` can be made readonly is a question for a ZSH developer (try the zsh-workers mailing list?) otherwise meanwhile don't mess around with the special variables.